# Azure service bus topic can use for private message

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

In contrast with Azure Service Bus Queues that allow us to deliver one-to-one, Azure Service Bus Topics allow us to deliver messages one-to-many. This means that we can deliver the same message to multiple clients that are called subscribers. This messaging system is basically an ESB system (Enterprise Service Bus), allowing to have a “publish/subscribe” communication.

I have multiple clients and i have created topic for each client. Whenever server send message to client, it just put message into client topic. Is it possible if i create single topic and multiple subscriber so that every client just listen only its message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible if i create single topic and multiple subscriber so
>   that every client just listen only its message?

It is certainly possible to do so. What you have to do is configure topic filtering rules so that each subscription gets the message based on the filter criteria defined for them. You can learn more about the filtering rules here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters.

From this link:

> Subscribers can define which messages they want to receive from a
>   topic. These messages are specified in the form of one or more named
>   subscription rules. Each rule consists of a condition that selects
>   particular messages and an action that annotates the selected message.
>   For each matching rule condition, the subscription produces a copy of
>   the message, which may be differently annotated for each matching
>   rule.

Comment: does this filtering rule affect the efficiency?

Comment: I am not aware of that, sorry.